# Why is Kerr Spacetime unstable?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, stability, kerr-metric

How do we know from the Kerr Metric that it is unstable near the Cauchy Horizon? What causes this unstability?

Comment: I think that is an open question.

Comment: I assume you're referring to the **mass inflation instability**, as described in Poisson (1990), [A look inside black holes](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1990JRASC..84..191P). That paper isn't specifically about rotating black holes, but it says "These features are very general and do not depen on our specialized, spherical model; our conclusions should then be valid for the case of an uncharged and rotating black hole."

Comment: It may not be unstable see recent paper cited here https://www.wired.com/story/at-long-last-mathematical-proof-that-black-holes-are-stable/

Answer (score 5):

That is a very good question. I will give you a rough argument of why we believe this to be true based on Bob and Alice. You can find a more detailed discussion at e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/79484.

Imagine Bob and Alice start together at $i$. Now, Bob has suicidical tendencies and decides to jump into a Kerr black hole, whereas Alice is more stable and decides to drift away to timelike infinity ($i^+$). In the penrose diagram below we represent the path of Bob with green and Alice by red.

[image: 1]

Now, Alice decides to periodically send light signals to Bob (blue lines below). Alice lives forever as you need infinite proper time to reach $i^ +$, however Bob quickly reaches the Cauchy horizon $\mathcal{CH}^ +_R$. Nevertheless, as we can see in the picture, the light signals from Alice will all eventually reach Bob. Although Alice sends them at a fixed frequency, to receive infinite signals in a finite proper time, Bob will receive signals with an increasing frequency, that goes to infinity right before the Cauchy horizon. We call this an infinite blue-shift. In rough terms, this blue-shift translates to a spacetime instability at the Cauchy horizon, so although Kerr possesses a Cauchy horizon, we expect generic small perturbations to blow up at the interior horizon.

Further question for the reader, why does this argument fail for asymptotically de-Sitter spacetimes? In fact, recent research showed that the Cauchy horizon of near-extremal Reissner–Nordström de-Sitter is stable with respect to generic perturbations.

Comment: So what eventually happens? What does this instability cause?

Comment: The Cauchy horizon becomes a null singularity

Comment: Is this an assumption or are there analytical calculations or numetical simulations showing this?